# Generate datatype with size in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing sql query where i need datatype with length like `int`, `nvarchar(250)`, `decimal(16,2)` which is defined in table column how can i generate this in sql.
i have tried this query but it not satisfy all data type

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE+
CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NOT NULL THEN 
'('+CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(20))+')' ELSE '' 
END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'User';
```

it doesn't give exact result for decimal and other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column sizes are stored in different fields. Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char'  THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, -1) AS VARCHAR(20)), 'max') + ')'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(20)) + ',' + CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'
            WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('datetime2')  THEN DATA_TYPE + '(' + CAST(DATETIME_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')' 
            ELSE DATA_TYPE
            END AS Data_Type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'User';
```

Comment: change the first case to `DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char'` and you have a winner.

Comment: Also, when `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` is -1 and `DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char'` then it means that is `nvarchar(max)`.